# Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 live USBs hard freeze after adding the universe repository

Tags: apt, 18.04, 20.04, live-usb, freeze

Booting an ASRock Z97 Extreme4 motherboard + Core i5 4690k Devil's Canyon CPU with a live USB of either Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 20.04 would hard freeze after adding the universe repository when the refresh was running. The results of `sudo apt update` showed the update was finished, and then Ubuntu would freeze. It would respond to the magic SysReq keys, but not to the mouse or Caps Lock key.

Comment: Ubuntu has both *year* format products (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) and *year.month* products (eg. 18.04) but they are different products. In the title you mention 18 & 20 implying *snap* only releases, but in tags you mention 18.04 & 20.04 which are different systems (*deb* based but can also use *snap* packages).  Please be clear with details & avoid contradiction.  18 & 20 cannot use 'universe' as it's a *deb* based repository that can only be used by *year.month* releases (eg. 18.04 & 20.04)

Answer (score 1):

There are several microcode packages in Ubuntu that are automatically installed.

The asker received a notification about the microcode being out of date. After updating the microcode the asker was able to install 11 BIOS updates that were needed, several of which were microcode updates. After that Ubuntu didn't freeze anymore and the universe repository worked fine.